# How many permutations of this number is divisible by 11

Tags: combinatorics

If I have a number with digits (they must contain them) 1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4, how many numbers are divisible by 11?
e.g. 11443322 is divisible by 11 but 14143322 is not. I'm not sure how to approach this

Answer (score 2):

For the number to be divisible by 11. the difference of sum of alternate digits  must be 0 or 11. for the difference to be zero.if a digit occupys an even place the other one must occupy an odd place. this is beacause you have 4 digits and each of them occurs twice.

so 1 group of 1,2,3,4 will occupy odd places while other will occupy even places.

so total possibilities are

$$4!*4!$$

now the difference should be eleven. total sum of digits is 20 if the difference should be 11 then sum of alternate digits should be 15.5 and 4.4 which is impossible. hence your answer is,

$$4!*4!$$

$$=576$$

Comment: did you get it.

Comment: Yep, thanks. Forgot that property of an 11-divisible number

Comment: Because $1+1+2+2+3+3+4+4=20$, we must have that the alternating digit sum difference is **even** and so for divisibility by $11$ must be zero.

Comment: The number 12124343 is divisible by 11, but you haven’t counted it. See the @andrew-woods answer below.

Comment: @Steve Kasa thanks. I realised I made amistake

Answer (score 2):

An integer is divisible by $11$ iff the sum of digits in even-indexed places equals the sum of digits in odd-indexed places.

In this example we have to partition the multiset $\{1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4\}$ into two multisets of the same size and with the same sum. There are two ways to do that:

$$\{1,2,3,4\}\text{ and }\{1,2,3,4\}\\\{1,1,4,4\}\text{ and }\{2,2,3,3\}$$

Therefore the number of solutions is $$4!^2+2\cdot\tbinom42^2=\boxed{648}$$ where the second term is doubled because we have to decide which 4-multiset to use for the even-indexed places.